# Vue 3 Transition group not showing data

Tags: vue.js

why  not showing my data? how do I solve this?

https://codepen.io/dhika345/pen/GRYJMzQ

want to make a carousel

this is to bypass "must code" error. ignore this

```html
askdaksdkasdkaskdaksdkaksdkaskdkaskdkasd
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the transition group. You need to specify a **key** value in the **v-for loop**, so that **vue** can know if the value inside has changed.  A solution like the one below might work.

```js
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toNext">next</button>
  <button style="margin-bottom: 10px" @click="toPrev">previous</button>
  
  <div class="container">
    <transition-group  tag="div" :name="back ? 'slideback' : 'slide'">
    <template v-for="(myItem, index) in myItems" >
      <div :key="currentIndex" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" v-if="currentIndex === index">
        {{ myItem }}
      </div>
    </template>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work. it's better and helpful if you can fork the codepen and solve the issue on it anyway

Comment: https://codepen.io/BarisOZER/pen/PoyqVre